# How do I know if an Email had a read receipt and how does this affect my different devices?

Tags: email, gmail

I've just had a discussion with a colleague about email read receipts and after a little Google research I haven't found any solid information on them.

As a recipient I open my email in either Mozilla Thunderbird or on my iPhone. My email is setup from a company managed G-mail account.

My question is how do I know that someone has requested a read receipt?

Will Thunderbird and my iPhone both send it back automatically, or will they request my approval?

How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

> Will Thunderbird and my iPhone both send it back automatically,
>   or will they request my approval?

In Thunderbird you can select what action should be taken.
The setting for this are under [Tools] [Account settings] "Return receipts"

[image: Screenshot of Thunderbirds account setting screen]

I have no iPhone, so someone else will have to answer that part.